# Как сделать треугольную деформацию блоков кроссбраузерно?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть блок `display:flex;` В нём 2 блока `flex: 0 0 50%;`

Как сделать такую стрелку между блоками и деформировать сами блоки?

Порылся в гугле, нашёл `clip-path`, но он работает только в `webkit`.

Comment: Как насчёт просто нарисовать эту стрелку в фотошопе?

Comment: Да, картинкой я знаю что можно сделать через :after, но интересует возможно ли сделать такую фишку на чистом css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
 margin: 200px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 background: #d4f2ff;
}

#crumbs {
 text-align: center;
}

 #crumbs ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
 }
  #crumbs ul li {
   display: inline;
  }
 
  #crumbs ul li a {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 50px;
   background: #3498db;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 30px 40px 0 80px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
   
   font-size: 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
  }
   #crumbs ul li a:after {
    content: "";  
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
      border-left: 40px solid #3498db;
    position: absolute; right: -40px; top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
   }
   
   #crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: "";  
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
      border-left: 40px solid #d4f2ff;
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
   }
 
    #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
     border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    #crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
     display: none; 
    }
    
    #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
     padding-right: 80px;
     border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    #crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
     display: none; 
    }
   
   #crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #fa5ba5;
   }
    #crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
     border-left-color: #fa5ba5;
    }
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#1">One</a></li>
 <li><a href="#2">Two</a></li>
 <li><a href="#3">Three</a></li>
 <li><a href="#4">Four</a></li>
 <li><a href="#5">Five</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Источник:  https://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderT/bmuwLfqr/

Этого в сети полно. Адаптивным должно быть? Про моб.версию думали?

Comment: откройте на полный экран

Comment: Не знаю что подразумеваете по кроссбраузерностью, но в 4-х основных отражается идентично. Яблочного нет для проверки...

Comment: Да отлично, то что нужно, я даже как-то не подумал про треугольники, на адаптиве я просто уберу :after и :before и flex-basis: 100% дам. Получится 2 обычных блока друг под другом.