# Как сверстать направленный вниз треугольный блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста как верстаются такие блоки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/895559/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/903893/262779

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно так (оставшиеся блоки добавите, думаю с этим проблем не будет):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #0064d9;
  background-image: url(https://www.gokunming.com/en/blog/image/big/12025.jpg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h3 {
  color:#f0f0f0; 
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-down {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.triangle {
  width: 100%;
}
.left-block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.right-block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-content {
  background: #39cccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
.left-triangle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.right-triangle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h3>WE CREATE DESIGN THAT YOU WILL LOVE</h3>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="left-block">
    <div class="left-triangle">
      <svg class="triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 500 85" preserveaspectratio="none">
        <polygon class="left" points="0,0   0,86   500.8,86   500.8,75.5" fill="#39cccc"></polygon>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-block">
    <div class="right-triangle">
      <svg class="triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="500 0 500 85" preserveaspectratio="none">
        <polygon class="right" points="1000,0   1000,86   500,86   500,75.5" fill="#39cccc"></polygon>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот ещё один вариант реализации:

*Можете посмотреть на Codepen, если Вам так удобнее: [ссылка](https://codepen.io/meine89/pen/OrZjKL)*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.test {
  padding: 72px 0px 220px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 101px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

.test::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  background: #ffffff;
  -ms-transform: skew(0, 4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0, 4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  -moz-transform: skew(0, 4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  -o-transform: skew(0, 4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  transform: skew(0, 4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
}

.test::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  background: #fff;
  -ms-transform: skew(0, -4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(0, -4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  -moz-transform: skew(0, -4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  -o-transform: skew(0, -4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
  transform: skew(0, -4.5deg) translate(0, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```