# Как вычесть одну фигуру из другой, что бы получилось как на примере

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxYxs.png)

Если у нас есть треугольник (скажем с острыми углами, не как на фото) сделанный при помощи css, и есть подобный ему треугольник находящийся в центре первого, можем ли мы так вычесть один треугольник из другого, что бы получить треугольную рамку (как на примере)

Comment: Попробуйте z-index, то есть меньший треугольник должен перекрывать больший. Остальное - чисто визуально.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929118/262779

Comment: это в рамках css кроссбраузерно не сделать но есть svg и он как раз для таких извращений и был сделан

Answer (score 3):

В общем как я и сказал - рисуем два треугольника - делаем сложние и накладываем pattern с картинкой и на выходе получаем эту штуку

Делал в `inkscape`, нарисовал один треугольник закрасил его чёрным (он даёт прозрачность) второй и залил его белым (он даёт непрозрачность)
сделал `объеденить` зашёл в тырнет и выбрал картинку и установил её в `pattern` и всё. `fill:url(pattern);` fill и есть тот самый background

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 148 87" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" 
           width="571.21461"
           height="334.54352"
     patternTransform="matrix(.26 0 0 .26 -299 74)"
     patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image x="-2.8e-14"
          y="8.4e-14"
          width="571" 
    height="335" 
    style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality"
    preserveAspectRatio="none"
    xlink:href="https://img.fonwall.ru/o/92/tropiki-more-plyaj-peyzaji1.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(-30 -167)">
  <path transform="matrix(.67 -.0053 .0082 .44 38 158)" 
        d="m95 172-71-128 147 2.6zm-1.4 46-107-199 220 4z" 
  style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:url(#pattern);"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Что то такое получилось, вам это было нужно?

```css
.helper-block {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.triangle-main {
  border: 100px solid #000;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


.triangle-child {
  border: 80px solid #fff;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="helper-block">
  <div class="triangle-main"></div>
  <div class="triangle-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, но только с условием что на фоне картинка, и что бы вместо #fff просвечивалась эта картинка

Comment: Этого не было указано в условие задания.